# bootstrap forms and column not aligning

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I'm trying to lay out a bootstrap form where the 1st row has 1 input and the 2nd row has 2 inputs. Here's a picture of it not working, you can see what i'm trying to do...
[image: layout columns not aligning]

Oh how i wish those boys would line up smartly!  I've been staring at this too long - it feels like a margin problem, but i'm probably just missing something obvious.

Can anyone spot my mistake?  I've gotten it down to bare bones here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container body-content"><br><br>

  <form>
  <div class="form-horizontal row">

    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Supplier</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Contact</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input class="form-control"/>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Phone</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input class="form-control"/>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope you can help!

Comment: You forgot a `<div class="row"></div>` around your 'supplier' input field.

Comment: @Roberrrt Thanks for the tip. Just tried and it changes the layout a little, doesn't fix it.  I don't think it's needed because of the parent `<div class="form-horizontal row">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of applying the number of columns to the form control, wrap all the controls in `<div>'s` with the desired number of columns:

```
<div class="container body-content"><br><br>
    <form>
      <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Supplier</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input class="form-control"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Contact</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input class="form-control"/>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Phone</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input class="form-control"/>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Here is a live demo
http://www.bootply.com/I5gUPVenbA

Comment: Thanks, that sorted me out!  Nice simple solution. I'm sure I was very close to that at one point, oh well.

Comment: I found that this will give double padding on small screens - 30px instead of 15px.  adding a row class here `<div class="form-horizontal row">` will fix that.

Comment: @EamonnM yes sir you are correct, the row will fix that extra 15px. I'm glad I could help